# How to Adding New Data into JSON Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

- I have a JSON having some data as an array , and I wanna add
  new data to JSON

**This is My JSON structure**

````
```[
{
"id":"JKT020",
"origin_time":"2020-06-30 12:00",
"location":"Jakarta, ID"
}
]```
````

**I want to add new data so it can be like this**

````
 ```[
{
"id":"JKT020",
"origin_time":"2020-06-30 12:00",
"location":"Jakarta, ID",
"flag":1
}
]```
````

Is it possible ? If it is can anyone tell me how to do that ? Thanks in advance.

And this is what I've been doing so far..

```
List data = json.decode(response.body);
      for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        data.add(data[i]["flag"]=1);
        print("object : " + data[i].toString());
      }
      });
```

It was printed like I want it, but return error in add line

The error said NoSuchMethodError: Class 'String' has no instance method '[]='

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have to Decode the JSON

`var data=json.decode("Your JSON")`

Now this is available as a list and map so you can add fields like

`data[key]=value;`

after that, you have to Encode it using `json.encode`

`var data1=json.encode(data);`
`

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to get the JSON formatted and mapped to a Model. This will not only help to do null checks but also increase the readability of your code.

You can use a simple Model like

```
class myModel {
  String id;
  String originTime;
  String location;
  int flag;

  myModel({this.id, this.originTime, this.location, this.flag});

  myModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    originTime = json['origin_time'];
    location = json['location'];
    flag = json['flag'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['origin_time'] = this.originTime;
    data['location'] = this.location;
    data['flag'] = this.flag;
    return data;
  }
}
```